# Keep console application window up on error

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a console application which I want to use to run as Windows Service. When I run the application manually I see the console window and there is an error, so the application is immediately closed. How can I keep my console app window up when error occur?

Here's my code:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
             Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                 {
                     webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                         .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5678", "https://0.0.0.0:5678");
                 }).UseWindowsService();
    }
```

I've tried to add `Console.ReadLine();` just after the line but doesn't work as expected. Once after error occurs application is closed.

```
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code into a try catch block to return the error to your console.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
          CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
             {
                 webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                     .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5678", "https://0.0.0.0:5678");
             }).UseWindowsService();
}
```

Comment: Why twice of `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` in Main?

Comment: mistake caused by copy pasta